# Query elasticsearch to find docs that don't have a key

Tags: elasticsearch

i have logs like:

```
{
  "a":"XXX",
  "b":"YYY",
  "token":"acquired"
}
```

Also, i have logs that do not have this `token` key set. Kibana's terms panel tells that they are around by showing them as `Missing fields(3047)`. How can i query all docs that do not have the `token` key set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query in ES for missing fields:

From: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_dealing_with_null_values.html

```
GET /my_index/posts/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter": {
                "missing" : { "field" : "token" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```